# Alerts in the server and wamp appear as errors

Tags: php, html, css

I have changed from app serv server to wamp server.  But it shows me mistakes. I think it alerts to appear as errors. For example, the first code does not work in wamp server but it works in appserv.

The second code works in both servers.  I want to make the first code work in wamp server.

**1**

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    $sql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1' ") or die();
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td></tr>
<? } ?>
```

**2**

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    $sql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1' ") or die();
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo"<tr><td>echo $row[username]</td></tr>";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: There's so much wrong with your `php` ideals is hard to say where it's going wrong .. First, don't use short tags -- Some servers don't like them.   use the full php tag IE `<?php`.  Next `echo"<tr><td>echo $row[username]</td></tr>";` <-- This won't wok on any `php` server I've ever maintained ..  Needs to be `echo"<tr><td>" .  $row[username] . "</td></tr>";`

Comment: @Zak variables are parsed in double-quoted strings, no problems at all. You should try it sometime. You're right about the short tags, very bad practice and no PHP servers support them by default. That's almost certainly the problem. If there were error messages we'd know for sure.